# Tensorflow 2.0: Import from tensorflow keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I can't import anything from keras if I import it from tensorflow.
I installed tensorflow 2.0 with `pip install tensorflow`, and while I'm able to write something like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()
```

If I try to import Sequential from keras

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Sequential
```

I got `Unresolved reference 'keras'`.
I've looked into every other post I could find and the information is contradictory, some say you have to install keras separately other says you just need to install tensorflow.
So far I've tried:

```py
from tensorflow.python import keras
```

```py
from tensorflow.contrib import keras
```

```py
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
```

Plus a bunch of combination of the above, none of these work.
Sorry if it's a dumb question but I've never struggled so much with a simple import before.

*Edit: Additionnal info, I'm on ubuntu 18.04, with Pycharm and a Python 3.6 virtual environment.*

### Answer:

It is actually a PyCharm bug !
Link here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38220
I tried the snippet of code proposed by @AYI here

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten

example_model = Sequential()
example_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(100, 100, 1)))
example_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
example_model.add(Flatten())
example_model.summary()
```

And actually runs normally *despite the warning and error displayed by Pycharm* !
[image: unjustified pycharm warning and error highlighting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way should help you "from tensorflow.keras.xxx import xxx"

Example of how to import Sequential in tensorflow 2.0:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

good luck~

---

Here is the Demo:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten

example_model = Sequential()
example_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(100, 100, 1)))
example_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
example_model.add(Flatten())
example_model.summary()
```

[image: model.summary]

Comment: @Inspi，Your solution “from tensorflow.keras import Sequential ” is very close, but needs a little improvement like this way "from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential".

Comment: ok so it turns out that this is actually a pycharm bug, ugh annoying but I'm closing this thread